# Delphi Interfaces and DLL's

Tags: delphi, memory-management, plugins, dll, interface

I'm trying to figure out a safe way of passing objects from a main app to a DLL (for a plugin system).
The idea is to use the main app's TZConnection (database access from Zeos Lib) in the dll's.

I'd rather not use Runtime Packages, and DLL must be the way to go (I don't need BPL's need to recompile each time, and have no idea of how to use COM).

I've been told it's possible to do it with Interfaces.

I've never used them before, but been messing around with it, and managed to do it... But, I don't know if I did it right (as in, safe).

Here's my Interface unit.

```
unit PluginIntf;

interface

uses
    ZConnection, ZDataSet;

type
    IQueryResult = interface   ['{743AB77E-7897-403E-A0D9-4D02748E565D}']
      function GetRecordCount: Integer;
      function GetDataSet: TZQuery;
    end;

    IPluginHost = interface   ['{A5A416B4-437E-4A1E-B228-0F94D54840B0}']
      function RunSql(const SQLString:WideString): IQueryResult;
    end;

    IPlugin = interface   ['{8D9591C3-5949-4F0A-883E-6ABD02597846}']
      function GetCaption: WideString;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

In IQueryResult, I'm passing a TZQuery. It works, but... Is it safe?
Is there any other way to wrap it in the Interface?

Thank you
Nuno Picado

Comment: TZQuery is part of the Zeos Lib. It's a descendant of TDataset, to get  a query result from a ??SQL server.

Comment: This code originally came from me in [this discussion](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=99781) in the Embarcadero forums. As I kept telling you in that discussion over and over, DO NOT expose direct access to objects across the DLL boundary, but you KEEP DOING IT. Stop it! Any object directly created by the app should only be directly accessible in the app's code. Any object directly created by the DLL should only be directly accessible in the DLL's code. Any object that needs to be shared should be wrapped in an interface that hides it.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for replying here, and thank you again for your replys over there.
I heard you over there, and that's why I kept asking for help, there, and now here. I just don't know, nor can find elsewhere, how to wrap it in the interface. Like I told you, I never worked with interfaces and this is why I asked for help - I just don't know how to do it.
Still, I wouldn't be able to get where I did without your help, and I understand just a little bit more about interfaces now. Just not enough to understand all its powers and limitations. Thank you!

Comment: When @RemyLebeau says "... should be wrapped in an interface that hides it", he is ***NOT*** referring to the _interface_ language construct. He is referring to the conceptual idea of the rules by which two things communicate. This is also commonly called "an interface", so I can understand your confusion. But this kind of interface is simply a collection of functions and procedures that give an indirect access to the internal objects of the other module.

Comment: Thank you Craig. I think I'm getting it now, so I'm moving to plan-B: Not trying no access another module's objects, each module will create and destroy it's own objects, and I'll be using Interfaces only with primitive datatypes (integer, bool) and COM managed WideString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TZQuery` is a class. Therefore it is not safe to pass one across the module boundary unless you use runtime packages. Use a class with DLLs and you actually have two separate types, one in each module.

You are correct that interfaces are safe for this but you need to restrict yourself to DLL interop safe types. That is simple types, records, pointers to arrays, interfaces, or combinations of these types.

You need to wrap `TZQuery` with an interface that exposes it's functionality.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
So, even with Interfaces, only simple data types. That does in fact mean I can't use datasets in the dll using the main app connection, since I can't "convert" an entire class to a simple datatype and recreate it in the dll. Is this so, or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You need to wrap the dataset functionality using valid interop types. For instance wrap it with an interface.

Comment: Any ideas on the "how"? :)
That's exactly what I don't know how to do. How do I wrap a class in an interface, and manage to use it on another module?

Comment: 1. Define an interface. 2. Create a class that implements the interface. 3. Give the class a single field, which is an object of the type being wrapped. 4. Implement the interface's methods by forwarding them to the wrapped object.

Comment: @nunopicado: I showed you examples of how **EXACTLY** to do what David has described. Was there something unclear about the examples I gave you earlier?

Comment: @nunopicado It is rather bad form to cross-post. You've now had both Remy and myself spending time telling you exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Remy: Actually, yes. It wasn't clear how to use the complete Dataset in the DLL with a TDatasource and a TDBGrid, which was my original problem. I AM indeed gratefull for your help, as you helped me to finally begin to understand Interfaces, which I knew absolutelly nothing about, and it'll be usefull in the future. In fact, I'm restructuring my plugin system based on your sample code so, I really am gratefull. You were wonderfull. I now believe that there's no safe way to do what I wanted originally, so I'm moving on with plan B. I hope to learn more from you in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know, and I'm sorry for that. In my defense, I can only point out what I believe we all understand: deadlines.
I was getting help from Remy over in Embarcadero Foruns, and obviously, wasn't understanding the concept of Interfaces "on-the-fly". When the "fountain drained", I had to search elsewhere.
Still, I didn't asked the same thing, I tried to create a continuity, exposing the code I already had so noone would have to waste more time than needed.
I want to thank you as well, as your help was also precious!

Comment: Are you still stuck? FWIW I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Sorry David. Somehow I missed this comment.
No, I'm not stuck anymore, at least on that problem.
Remy's help with creating the Inteface, and yours on the clarification solved the problem.

Thank you very much!